# How to arrange events and data in chronological order in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a task to sort out the below data in chronological order and list the data based on the timestamp.

If someone can guide me through the logic, I can try to write the code by myself.

**Input:**

```
Timestamp         : 2017-02-13 12:07:25.040000 UTC
Event Name        : linkManager/link-event
DataFields        : [srcSwName:X, srcPortName:ethernet30, dstSwName:X, dstPortName:ethernet3, fabricLinkEventType:X reason:Port Down]

Timestamp         : 2017-02-13 12:07:26.040000 UTC
Event Name        : eventManager/event
DataFields        : [srcSwName:X, srcPortName:ethernet30, dstSwName:X, dstPortName:ethernet3, fabricLinkEventType:X, reason:Port Down]

Timestamp         : 2017-02-13 12:07:25.040000 UTC
Event Name        : linkManager/link-event
DataFields        : [srcSwName:X, srcPortName:ethernet29, dstSwName:X, dstPortName:ethernet3, fabricLinkEventType:X reason:Port Down]

Timestamp         : 2017-02-13 12:07:26.040000 UTC
Event Name        : eventManager/event
DataFields        : [srcSwName:X, srcPortName:ethernet30, dstSwName:X, dstPortName:ethernet3, fabricLinkEventType:X, reason:Port Down]

Timestamp         : 2017-02-13 12:07:25.040000 UTC
Event Name        : eventManager/event
DataFields        : [srcSwName:X, srcPortName:ethernet30, dstSwName:X, dstPortName:ethernet3, fabricLinkEventType:X, reason:Port Down]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Timestamp         : 2017-02-13 12:07:25.040000 UTC
Event Name        : linkManager/link-event
DataFields        : [srcSwName:X, srcPortName:ethernet30, dstSwName:X, dstPortName:ethernet3, fabricLinkEventType:X reason:Port Down]

Timestamp         : 2017-02-13 12:07:25.040000 UTC
Event Name        : linkManager/link-event
DataFields        : [srcSwName:X, srcPortName:ethernet29, dstSwName:X, dstPortName:ethernet3, fabricLinkEventType:X reason:Port Down]

Timestamp         : 2017-02-13 12:07:25.040000 UTC
Event Name        : eventManager/event
DataFields        : [srcSwName:X, srcPortName:ethernet30, dstSwName:X, dstPortName:ethernet3, fabricLinkEventType:X, reason:Port Down]

Timestamp         : 2017-02-13 12:07:26.040000 UTC
Event Name        : eventManager/event
DataFields        : [srcSwName:X, srcPortName:ethernet30, dstSwName:X, dstPortName:ethernet3, fabricLinkEventType:X, reason:Port Down]

Timestamp         : 2017-02-13 12:07:26.040000 UTC
Event Name        : eventManager/event
DataFields        : [srcSwName:X, srcPortName:ethernet30, dstSwName:X, dstPortName:ethernet3, fabricLinkEventType:X, reason:Port Down]
```

Comment: You can find a way to `read` the file, and `for each line`, `check` if it's a `Timestamp`, an `Event Name` or a `Datafields`. If so, `append` it in a specific `list` (one list for each variable: `list_timestamp`, `list_event_name` and `list_datafields`) and then you can `zip` the lists you've created and `sort` the zipped list `by timestamp`. After all this proccess you can recreate the file layout by using a `for loop` while you `print` each variable with `.format()`

Answer (score 0):

lets imagine this is in a file

```
import itertools

with open('filename') as f:
    # Extract blocks by splitting on empty lines
    blocks = [list(val) for key, val in 
              itertools.groupby(f, lambda x: bool(x.rstrip()))
              if key]

    # Now the top line on each block has a timestamp so compare it:
    blocks.sort(key=lambda x: x[0].split(':')[-1])

with open('out_file', 'w') as f:
    # Write back the blocks with a new line separator to new file:
    for block in blocks:
       f.writelines(block + ['\n'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `read` your file and load it into, for example, a `list`. Then convert the first value field of `TimeStamp` which is represented into `UTC` timezone into `timestamp`.

For example:

```
Timestamp         : 2017-02-13 12:07:25.040000 UTC
```

which contains `2017-02-13 12:07:25.040000` could be replaced by `timestamp` using `datetime` module like this example:

```
from datetime import datetime
a = '2017-02-13 12:07:25.040000'
b = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").timestamp()
print(b)
>>> 1486984045.04
```

Now, you can create a `method` or you can simply use a `lambda` function like this way:

```
# Note: x should be a string
get_timestamp = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").timestamp()
```

Then, you can `sort` your `list` by the returned `timestamp` data of your new `method` or `lmabda` function.